# What is the difference between placing "allScriptsTimeout" inside and outside of "jasmineNodeOpts" in protractor conf.js?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

There is some difference when I place the setting `allScriptsTimeout` inside and outside of the `jasmineNodeOpts` in protractor conf.js.

Please see the below examples, but in this which one is valid?

Outside jasmine node options:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: "jasmine2",

multiCapablities: [
    {'browserName' : 'chrome'},
    {'browserName':'firefox'}
],

allScriptsTimeout : 20000,

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    print: function () {
    },
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 400000
    //allScriptsTimeout: 550000
  }

}
```

Within jasmine node options:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: "jasmine2",

 multiCapablities: [
    {'browserName' : 'chrome'},
    {'browserName':'firefox'}
 ],

 jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    print: function () {
    },
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 400000
    allScriptsTimeout: 200000
  }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

`allScriptsTimeout` should be part of config options and not `jasmineNodeOpts`. Please see below an extract on the significance of this setting.

> The timeout in milliseconds for each script run on the browser. This
>   should be longer than the maximum time your application needs to
>   stabilize between tasks.

Jasmine provides only one timeout option - `defaultTimeoutInterval`. The documentation states this for `defaultTimeoutInterval`:

> Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.

[Protractor official documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L550)  is the source of truth on different config options.

Comment: Yeah i have thought of the same but still my one set of test cases run smoothly when it is inside and other set runs without any error when it is outside. So got into confusion :(

Comment: Yeah .. I understand it's confusing.. but the allscript timeouts will come into picture on backend angular scripts trigerred from your app. So you will not see any difference in how your tests to run uf your app generally doesnt make behind the scenes script calls. And if you have that option in jasmineNodeOpts it doesnt make any difference as Jasmine dorsnt recognize such a config

Comment: cool thanks for the clarification. Then i am gonna use it in normal way. Thanks a lot

Comment: @AdityaReddy I have many `*.e2e-spec.ts` file. Does the `allScriptsTimeout` apply to **each** of the `e2e-spec.ts` script file or **all** of the `*.e2e-spec.ts` files?